# How to get MultiValued Attribute in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all users which are admin from user_info table. In user_info table the groups column ins multivalued attribute. What I've tried is:

```
 select * from user_info where 'admin' IN Split(',',groups);
```

I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Split(',',groups)

**user_info table**

```
username     |   groups         |
---------------------------------
ABC@mail.com |   superadmin,admin
```

**groups table**

```
 groupID(AutoIncr)     |   groups         |
---------------------------------
1                      |   superadmin     |
2                      |   admin          |
```

Comment: The old comma separated items issue... I'm sorry, but that will only cause you lots of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
select * 
  from user_info
  where find_in_set('admin', groups);
```

really tho, that is a crutch around a fundamentally broken design.

Answer (score 1):

For your solution this is a working query

select * from user_info where find_in_set('admin', groups);

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97c4b/1

**BUT**

You should'nt work with your table structure. If you can change it, change it! Normalize your schema and you will have much less problems and better performance!

In your case you should use a schema like this

```
create table users (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  username varchar(255))
  ;

  insert into users (id, username) values (1, 'ABC@mail.com');

  create table groups (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(255)

  );

  insert into groups (id, name) values (1, 'superadmin');
  insert into groups (id, name) values (2, 'admin');


create table user_groups (
  user_id int,
  group_id int
);

insert into user_groups (user_id, group_id) values (1,1);
insert into user_groups (user_id, group_id) values (1,2);
```

Then you can select

```
select * from users u
join user_groups ug on (ug.user_id = u.id)
join groups g on (ug.group_id = g.groupid)
where g.name = 'admin';
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82fa/2